# Peer certificate rejected by ChainVerifier

Tags: java, ssl, soap, keystore

I have a Java11 application that exposes a SOAP endpoint on a Linux Centos7 server.  I can call the SOAP endpoint from my localhost successfully via Postman.

- https://abx.co/xyz/soapWS

We have a client who when they try call the endpoint (via their SAP system), they get the following error message:

> Peer certificate rejected by ChainVerifier

[image]

Any ideas please?

I thought the issue may be that that the client needs to ad a certificate to their keysore, but my localhost does not have one, and it works. Do they maybe have to upgrade to a higher version of TLS?